# How do I change the icon of a Epiphany web app?

Tags: webapps, epiphany

The webapps just take a thumb of whatever image they can find on the page, can I customise it?

Answer (score 7):

For Gnome-Shell (Ubuntu 12.10), the image is located at ~/.config/epiphany/app-epiphany* (where the * in app-epiphany* is the web app name followed by and some additional numbers/letters)

Comment: Additionally, you'll want to open the respective folder and edit the app-icon.png inside with gimp (or create a new one with inkscape then export it as a png).

Answer (score 2):

Replace the image file called `app-icon.png` in `~/.config/epiphany/app-epiphany*` or `~/.gnome2/epiphany/app-epiphany*` (where the `*` in `app-epiphany*` is the web app name followed by and some additional numbers/letters).

For instance, for a webapp called coolap, it could be `~/.config/epiphany/app-epiphany-coolapp-12512912r1unr1i25n124/app-icon.png`.

Then restart Unity (ALT+F2 ,then type “unity” and press ENTER) or GNOME Shell (ALT+F2, type "r", ENTER).

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/install-epiphany-320-with-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me the path was `~/.local/share/epiphany-appname-*`.

Filename is `app-config.png` as well.

- Epiphany v3.36.4
- Gnome v3.36.8
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score -1):

Try [menulibre](https://launchpad.net/menulibre).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:menulibre-dev/devel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

Menulibre is really easy to use - hopefully it'll work with the webapps (it works with Unity-webapps). You can access it from the settings menu, or just type "menu" into the dash, and open the one called "Menu Editor."

Also, check out the developer's site [here](http://www.smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/).

[image: Menulibre Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

For me the path was ~/.local/share/org.gnome.Epiphany.WebApp-appname-*. Inside that directory I could find "app-icon.png". Replacing that icon with a different one worked great after restarting Gnome like @elchapu described in his answer.

I'm using Epiphany 3.38.3 on Fedora 33.

Comment: Fedora is off-topic here. What you found in Fedora may or may not be relevant. In this case it isn't.